# How do I set multiple cookies using a CFHTTPMessageRef?

Tags: macos, cocoa, cookies, http-headers

In Cocoa, calling `CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields()` on a `CFHTTPMessageRef` returns a `CFDictionaryRef`. This suggests that the header fields are stored in a `CFDictionaryRef` in the `CFHTTPMessageRef`.  So, using `CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue()` with the same key ("Set-Cookie") will overwrite any previous values for that key leaving only the last (and the last cookie does indeed get set in the client-side browser using this method and returning the `CFHTTPMessageRef` data via a socket to the client). With this limitation, how do we set multiple cookies using a `CFHTTPMessageRef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `CFHTTPMessageRef` does store the headers in a mutable `CFDictionaryRef`, there really isn't a great way to set multiple cookies using `CFHTTPMessageRef`. You can fold them using a comma separator for each cookie though this never seemed to work for me. What did work was to put a placeholder for the Set-Cookie header and then, before sending the data derived from the `CFHTTPMessageRef`, converting the data to a string and adding separate Set-Cookie headers for each cookie (replacing the placeholder using `CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue()`. This works but only if the body payload is a string. If it's binary data (such as an image), then additional steps are required to make sure the data is maintained.

Evidently, this is a known issue with `CFHTTPMessageRef` as it is not compliant with the latest HTTP specs: [rdar://15933483](http://openradar.appspot.com/15933483),